# How should I interpret this simple integral problem?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

During AP Calculus today, my class came across a very strange problem, it went like this:

> If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[1,3]$ and $2\leq f(x)\leq 4$, what is the greatest possible value of $\int_1^3f(x)dx$?

I assumed this meant the maximum value of $f(x)$ is 4, and the minimum is 2. The area would therefore be 8 at most, but that is not the correct answer.

The easiest way for me to understand it was to treat the question as if it was asking for the area between $f(x) = 2$ and $f(x) = 4$ on the interval $[1,3]$. How my teacher explained it was the lowest f(x) value was 2 and the highest was 4, so you take out the area between $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = 2$. This means the answer would be 4.

I want to know what interpretation of the question seems right, and I'd like an explanation of this question in a different way. My teacher said this was an AP exam question, so this is somewhat important.

Comment: Small correction, this doesn't change my question: I meant to say the maximum possible value is 4, and the minimum possible value is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teacher is wrong this time.

Consider the following example: let $f(x) = 4$ for all $x$
(that is, $f$ is the constant function with value $4$).
Then

1. $f$ is continuous on $[1,3].$
2. $2 \leq f(x) \leq 4.$

Therefore $f$ is one of the functions that satisfies the problem conditions.
But

$$ \int_1^3 f(x)\,dx = \int_1^3 4\,dx = 8.$$

This does not prove that $8$ is the maximum,
but it most certainly proves that $4$ is *not* the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You are not given that $f(x)$ achieves $2$ or $4$, just that it is always within $[2,4]$.  $f(x)=3$ is one function that satisfies the requirement.  $f(x)=4$ is another and the integral of that is $8$ as you say.  There is no reason to subtract the area below $2$ and $8$ is correct.